# How to add a custom symbol to LaTeX?

Tags: macros, symbols

Suppose I need some crazy custom symbol for personal use.

e.g.
when I write `\foobar`, LaTeX should show the symbol.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Metafont fonts for Klingon can be found on CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=klingon&search_type=description. :)

Comment: Remark, see [characters - Declaring a Specific Math Symbol in a TTF Font (LuaLaTeX) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643188/declaring-a-specific-math-symbol-in-a-ttf-font-lualatex) to make "custom symbol" automatically support boldening inside a mathbf etc.., and see [fonts - Defining a math symbol of variable sizes in XeTeX with \Umathchardef - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344461/defining-a-math-symbol-of-variable-sizes-in-xetex-with-umathchardef/344462#344462) for automatically changing size.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simplest way would be to save it as a pdf (or eps if you're using latex) and then define

```
\newcommand*\foobar{\includegraphics{crazycustomsymbol}}
```

Comment: save what as a pdf?

Comment: @MachineCharmer: Your "crazy custom symbol."

Comment: Will it work if I use `crazycustomsymbol.png` instead of `crazycustomsymbol.pdf`?

Comment: @MachineCharmer: Sure!

Comment: I tried this but the symbol is just huge! How can I adjust the size?

Comment: You may need to add this line:
`\newcommand*\foobar{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics{xxxx.png}}}}`
so that the new symbol is aligned with text.

Comment: In addition to answer 1: make your symbol adjust to font size by setting width or height of the included graphics to a multiple of em or ex: \newcommand*\foobar{\includegraphics[width=.8em]{crazycustomsymbol}}

Comment: in overleaf i have to write it as $\foobar$

Answer (score 41):

As TH mentioned, you can create a graphic in an external program and include it as a picture. Preferably you would use a vector drawing software such as adobe illustrator or the (free) software inkscape. This way scaling the image will not change the quality (don't use raster graphics such as jpg).

Of course you can also use a code based approach e.g. with the tikz or pstricks package

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,1ex);%
\draw (0.5ex,0) -- (1.3ex,0.8ex);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
Some text and the symbol \foo{} or scaled \foo{scale=2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned this. I was going to, but as I don't actually know TikZ or pstricks, I figured I'd let someone else.

Comment: I do exactly this!  I have customised `\Implies` and `\Iff` to make them a bit larger and longer for presentations.

Comment: I gues that tikz will re-compute the symbol each time you use it. Is it possible to "evaluate" the tikzpicture once and then reuse it?

Comment: Yes it will. You can of course create a pdf picture from your tikz drawing and include it. Also tikz has a externalize library that will evaluate the picture once, creates a pdf from it and inlcudes the pdf-picture in future compiling processes. I guess this would be a bit much for a symbol, so if you like tikz, create the symbol in an extra document and use pdfcrop to trim the resulting pdf.

Comment: @Bruno, Martin H: You could use a `\savebox` to store the rendered picture and reuse it. This way it is only drawn once.

Comment: Now the real question: how to respect the current font size? *Without* creating a custom font, that is …

Comment: For simple shapes, I found a quick introduction to tikz here: http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf

Comment: @MartinH I love this answer, now big question: Is there a way to make it bold without creating a completely new command/image?

Comment: Can you customize the width of the glyph? For instance, is it possible to make it be 60% as wide as it is tall?

Comment: @KonradRudolph (comment 10 years ago, but also for future readers) [Adapt graphic size to surrounding text - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489745/adapt-graphic-size-to-surrounding-text)

Answer (score 22):

Yet another way of including custom symbols is by composing new ones through superimposing glyphs, which is demonstrated in the [symbols-a4](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) manual on page 103.

Here's an example:

```
\newcommand{\starcup}{$\sqcup$\kern-0.58em{$\star$}}
```

Which gives:

[image: starcup is an all new glyph]

As Martin Scharrer points out, the use of ex or em as a unit for kerning respects the font size. You can also use (as I did in the first revision of this example) points for absolute positioning.

Comment: You could use `ex` or `em` as unit for the `\kern` to get font size relative kerning. Also `\rlap` could be used to simply lap the second symbol over the first.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thanks, I have updated my answer to use proportional units. I attempted to use `\rlap` but for some reason the glyphs were set on different lines. Moreover, the glyphs were (predictably) left-aligned and thus the star was off-centre and in need of `kern`. As such I am not sure that `\rlap` constitutes a better method.

Comment: Yes, `\rlap` alone only works well when the symbols have approximately the same width. See [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another/12900#12900) where I use a box to center one symbol on top of another one.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: would using muskips be better/worse?

Comment: @Bruno: honestly I don't know muskips very well, so I can't tell. I have to read about them in *The TeXBook* again.

Comment: @Bruno: in general, using relative units in the same mode or direction is always a good idea.  so, in math, mu, in horizontal text mode, em, and in vertical text mode, ex.  then they will scale properly when you change the base size.