# combining existing symbols

Tags: fonts, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overlay symbol with another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another)

How can I create a new symbol by carefully overlaying and repositioning two existing symbols in the box that tex allocates for a single symbol?

Comment: I think ["overlay symbol with another"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another) already covers this. See e.g. [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another/12900#12900) to it.

Comment: Here is [another post on the same topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-to-latex/13602#13602)

Comment: If the question Martin linked doesn't help you, please state more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: As it's a duplicate and there's no question any more following the comments, I'll close this question. I hope the linked answers could help you.