# \Theta with square

Tags: symbols

I'm using `\Theta` for some concept in my work, then I need a variation of such concept.
I was thinking to use `\Theta` symbol with a square instead of a circle.

How can I obtain such symbol?

Thanks

Comment: Would `\boxminus` be ok? You need to load `amssymb` to use it.

Comment: I don't think those symbols would be that distinguishable. Why not use an alternative symbol? Or perhaps `\Theta'`?

Comment: You can try to use a reverse search like [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). No much luck there, the best was `\boxminus` from `amssymb` package. You can also try to include a previously made image, but it can be a pain to use.

Comment: How about [`\Xi`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y549O.png)?

Comment: Check out:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-to-latex

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257923/how-to-make-your-own-latex-math-symbol

Comment: How about `\varTheta`?

Comment: The “circle” in `\Theta` is not geometric, while a square is; I don't think a visual connection would be obvious.

Comment: Sorry, but introducing a new own letter, that doesn't have a name, doesn't sound like a good idea. Certainly if I were reviewing your paper, I would not allow this through. Both @Werner 's suggestions sound great: `\Theta'`, `\Xi`, `\Theta_1`, `\tilde\Theta`, ... do you really need a new symbol?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength\thetawidth
\newlength\thetaheight

\newcommand*{\SquareTheta}{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\mathsurround}{0pt}%
    \settowidth{\thetawidth}{$\Theta$}%
    \settoheight{\thetaheight}{$\Theta$}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      x=\thetawidth,
      y=\thetaheight,
    ]
    \draw[line width=.1\thetawidth, line cap=round]
      (0.125,.05\thetawidth) -- +($(0,1)-(0,.1\thetawidth)$)
      (0.875,.05\thetawidth) -- +($(0,1)-(0,.1\thetawidth)$);
    \draw[line width=.05\thetaheight, line cap=butt]
      (0.125,.025\thetaheight) -- +(0.75,0)
      ($(0.125,1)-(0,.025\thetaheight)$) -- +(0.75,0);
    \draw[line width=.1\thetawidth, line cap=butt]
      (0.275,0.5) -- (0.725,0.5);
    \draw[line width=.0375\thetaheight, line cap=butt]
      ($(0.275,0.5)-(0,.1\thetawidth)$) -- +(0,.2\thetawidth)
      ($(0.725,0.5)-(0,.1\thetawidth)$) -- +(0,.2\thetawidth);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  $\Theta$ \\[1pt]
  $\SquareTheta$ \\[1pt]
  $\Theta\SquareTheta$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]