# Do we have script Greek symbol?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Since we have `$\mathscr{F}$`, the script version of an English alphabet, do we also have the script version of a Greek alphabet such as `$\Omega$`?

I have tried `$\mathscr{\Omega}$` but nothing had happened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is a bit vague. If you find some font which has such symbols, you might use them with use of the package `fontspec`.

But to answer the question "do we have script Greek symbol?" in the meaning of predefined in LaTeX or some package I say: no.

The package `unicode-math` handles 6 very common Math fonts you will find in many of the examples here and here is their list of normal weight alphabetical symbols from their documentation:

[image]

No Greek script can be found here. As there is no Unicode-block for such symbols either, I guess it will get difficult to find something.

My recommendation: Search for some font of hand-written Greek, download and install it, and do:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\mscrOmega}{\text{\fontspec{yourFont.otf}\symbol{"03A9}}}

\begin{document}
$\mscrOmega$ \mscrOmega
\end{document}
```

Comment: @EricClapton, did you ever manage to find any Greek script?    Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To complement LaRiFaRi's answer, Microsoft's Gabriola font do have some capital Greek letters that look handwritten, but they just miss a slight italic aspect. A clean way to resolve this would be to use XeLatex with Gabriel font and fake the slant [with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251888/slant-character-manually-in-tex-coding). If you just need a single letter, you could also fake the slant with some design/vector software (say inkscape) and [import the resulting symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-to-latex). Result with a capital cursive theta:

[image: A cursive capital theta]