# Slant character manually in TeX coding

Tags: slanted

How to slant some character in the text of roman font (I don't want to use italics coding)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Using `\textsl{slanted}` should do.

Comment: I need this to work in TeX not in LaTex. for example ${\bf n}$
The output required is slanted "n" in bold roman

Comment: Then `{\sl slanted\/}`

Comment: could you please guide what is wrong in my code
${\sl \tf="OTb65e897d_B"n}$
${\tf="OTb65e897d_B"{\sl n}}$

Comment: What should `\tf` do? And recall that font declarations are not cumulative, so `\sl\bf` is equivalent to `\bf`. See my edited answer.

Comment: This question is only 39min old - it is too early to close.

Comment: I don't know if this pdflatex technique at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box can be adapted for plain TeX, but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 11):

## Slant font of plain TeX

The plain TeX format defines `\tensl` to hold the slanted (not italics) variant of the default CM roman font, from `plain.tex`:

```
\font\tensl=cmsl10 % slanted roman
```

It can be used via `\tensl` or the higher level command `\sl`:

```
Default font vs.~{\sl slanted font.}
\bye
```

For more details, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251891/16967) of egreg.

> [image: Result slanted font]

## Slanting with TikZ

TikZ can be used with plain TeX, it allows arbitrary slant angles:

```
\input tikz

\def\slant#1#2{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base), xslant=tan(#1)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, xslant=tan(#1)](X){#2};%
}

Normal, \slant{9.46}{slanted,} \slant{45}{larger slanting,}
\slant{-15}{slanted to the left.}

\bye
```

> [image: Result TikZ]

Answer (score 7):

The Plain TeX format provides `\sl`, so

```
This is {\sl slanted\/} type
```

will do.

If you need “boldface slanted”, you have to define the font:

```
\font\tenslbf=cmbxsl10
\def\slbf{\tenslbf}
```

(the definition is just to possibly support math mode, if needed).

Full example:

```
\font\tenslbf=cmbxsl10
\def\slbf{\tenslbf}

This is {\sl slanted\/} type.

This is {\slbf boldface slanted\/} type.

\bye
```

[image]

Here's the basic support for math:

```
\font\tenslbf=cmbxsl10
\newfam\slbffam
\textfont\slbffam=\tenslbf
\def\slbf{\tenslbf\fam\slbffam}

This is {\sl slanted\/} type.

This is {\slbf boldface slanted\/} type.

${\sl n}\neq{\slbf n}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks bro. Actually I am using 3B2 softwareIn this it has option to def. as I coded. \def \bf {\tf="XXX"} means assign the font for \bf code. It has no option for create external cls file. The above coding is not supported in 3B2. Thanks for your swift reply and answers.

Comment: @Mydeen That I know of, 3B2 no longer uses TeX at all so that is perhaps not a surprise!

Comment: Is that any other way to get the output in 3B2.

Comment: @Mydeen 3B2 is commercial software and presumably has appropriate support. If there is a TeX back end in the version you have then it should be accessible somewhere. If it doesn't we can't really help.