# Can custom ligatures be defined by user?

Tags: symbols, ligatures, reflection

I hope I was not wrong in assuming that such a question has never been posted, since I haven't checked.

Thinking about a girl, whose name is Gioia, and noticing that upper case `G` and and lower case `a` are similar in shape to `6`, I tried to write her name as `6ioiX` where `X` should be a vertically mirrored `6`.

"Bando alle ciance", what I've drawn is this:

[image]

How do you suggest me to proceed?

I don't think it's difficult at all to mirror the first two chars, but I don't know if any ligature of the `6` with the `i` char exists... Neither I know if there is a special char having a `6`-like shape which supports this ligature.

Is making custom ligature something that can be defined in `LaTeX` somehow?

Love. It makes me wanna do anything possible, or even impossible, ahahahah!

Comment: For love, you might also consider acrostics: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121440/tex-assistance-in-writing-hidden-acrostics

Comment: I still don't have a letter to write, ahahah! :D

Comment: I see... she's your girl, but she doesn't know it yet!

Comment: You got the point! This still happens! (I'm 28, ahahah)

Comment: You can see several techniques in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244812/how-could-i-write-my-name-for-example-to-look-like-the-latex-logo/244814

Comment: What a bad impression I've made on @egreg! :(

Comment: I always remember my students about the “doccie pubbliche” board once showing in my city.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being a collection of clipped and scaled glyphs, it is *very* font dependent.  Obviously, this is not creating a ligature, but merely piecing together an image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,trimclip,graphicx}
\newcommand\Gi{\clipbox{0pt -.1ex .65ex -.1ex}{6}\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \clipbox{.52ex -.1ex 0pt .4ex}{6}}{\scalebox{2}[1]{\clipbox{.52ex 1.1ex 0pt -.1ex}{6}}}%
  {O}{l}{F}{F}{S}\kern-.75ex \i}
\newcommand\ia{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\Gi}}
\begin{document}
\Gi o\ia
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complex clipping (different vertical scales of the pieces/parts), again in Computer Modern

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,trimclip,graphicx}
\newcommand\Gi{\clipbox{0pt -.1ex .65ex -.1ex}{6}\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \clipbox{.52ex -.1ex 0pt .45ex}{6}}{\scalebox{2}[1.22]{\clipbox{.55ex 1.14ex 0pt -.1ex}{6}}}%
  {O}{l}{F}{F}{S}\kern-.75ex \i\kern-.1ex}
\newcommand\ia{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\Gi}}
\begin{document}
\Gi o\ia
\end{document}
```

[image]

and then using Baskervald (2 variants):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,trimclip,graphicx}
\newcommand\Gi{\clipbox{0pt -.1ex .77ex -.1ex}{6}\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \clipbox{.50ex -.1ex 0pt .4ex}{6}}{\scalebox{1.7}[1.4]{\clipbox{.545ex 1.37ex 0pt -.1ex}{6}}}%
  {O}{l}{F}{F}{S}\kern-.66ex \i\kern-.1ex}
\newcommand\ia{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\Gi}}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\begin{document}
\Gi o\ia

\renewcommand\Gi{\clipbox{0pt -.1ex .85ex -.1ex}{6}\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \clipbox{.42ex -.1ex 0pt .49ex}{6}}{\scalebox{1.83}[1.83]{\clipbox{.49ex 1.377ex 0pt -.1ex}{6}}}%
  {O}{l}{F}{F}{S}\kern-.68ex \i\kern-.1ex}

\Gi o\ia
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An undoubtedly nice solution. I'll check the code as soon as I can, so that I can appreciate it and possibly ask you to help me "trim" it a little bit :D

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this?

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox[origin=b]{-25}{\large6}%
\kern-.3em\i\kern-.05em o\kern-.05em%
\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=b]{-25}{\large6}\kern-.3em\i}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to admit that the rotate box trick is excelent and effective. This way the two `6`s have a perfect ligature with the `i`s. The only thing I don't like is that the two sides or the round part of the 6s is inclined.

Answer (score 2):

Today I've had time to search on TeXSE for the most proper tools to produce that "ligature-like" arrangement of chars.

I've just run into [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251890/87996), which gave me the the idea to improve (imho, obviously!) @Fran's answer, which I found very very smart!

The final code is the following,

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\slant#1#2{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base), xslant=tan(#1)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, xslant=tan(#1)](X){#2};%
}
\def\resize#1#2{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base), yscale=#1]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, yscale=#1](X){#2};%
}

\newcommand{\gi}{\resize{.94}{\slant{30}{6}}\hskip-3.8pt\slant{10}{i}}
\newcommand{\ia}{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\gi}}

\usepackage{baskervald}

\begin{document}

\gi\hskip-1.5pt o\hskip-1.5pt\ia

\end{document}
```

which produces a quite good result:

[image]

I would have preferred an upright text, like the last example by @Steven, which gives a good result too. But maybe obtaining a perfect result concerns creating a symbol from scratch, and that'd be not LaTeX.

I'll wait some day more for a visionary guy to answer! :D

Comment: I've waited for someone taking the TikZ sledgehammer :)

Comment: *Sledgehammer*! [Ahahahahah](http://ilnostrospazio.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/morire-dal-ridere.jpg), please, tag Till Tantau and Christian Feuersänger, since they will surely appreciate this comment! Man, you litterally "laid me on the ground"!