# How to italicize a font that doesn't have a italicize option?

Tags: fonts, italic, truetype

I want to italicize the font Play in my document, but the truetype of that font does not have an italic option as seen on https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Play?query=play. Is there a way for me to italicize this font in Latex? I know google docs somehow does it. Also I am using https://github.com/ccebinger/CTAN_Play/blob/master/Play/texmf/tex/latex/Play/Play.sty to install the font Play in Latex if that makes any difference.

Comment: Refer `Heiko's` answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251888/slant-character-manually-in-tex-coding

Comment: would be easier to use the font directly with luatex than use pdftex and the specific package, most likely (`fontspec` has support for slanting fonts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use luatex or xetex, `fontspec` can slant the font:

[image]

This with luatex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
AutoFakeSlant=0.3,
BoldFont=Play-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont=Play-Regular.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=Play-Bold.ttf
]
{Play-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}

One two \textbf{three} \textit{four}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hope this is the best suggestion for this question, fantastic