# Generate these symbols with amssymb

Tags: fontspec, amssymb

I am trying to generate these symbols using amssymb:

[image]

Some of them don't show up, like the triangles. How can I reproduce them as close as possible?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage[cal = txupr]{mathalpha}
\begin{document} 
$\bullet$
$\blacksquare$ 
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}
$\blacktriangle$ 
$\blacktriangledown$ 
$\blacktriangleleft$ 
$\blacktriangleright$
$\bigstar$ 
$\boxtimes$
\end{document}
```

Comment: where do the symbols come from? Could be possible to generate the svg, eps o pdf file an use it as: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-to-latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the font you are using simply does not support those symbols. If you pick a font that does then the symbols appear:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}  
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX}
%\usepackage[cal = txupr]{mathalpha}
\begin{document} 

bullet:$\bullet$

blacksquare $\blacksquare$ 

blacksquare rotated \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}

blacktriangle $\blacktriangle$ 

blacktriangledown $\blacktriangledown$ 

blacktriangleleft $\blacktriangleleft$ 

blacktriangleright $\blacktriangleright$

bigstar $\bigstar$ 

boxtimes $\boxtimes$

\end{document}
```

Note: In general you should either use `amssymb` or `unicode-math`. In case you decide to use the unicode you should replace the `\blacksquare` command to `\mdblksquare`. You could also comment out the `unicode-math` and stay only with `amssymb` - in which case you'll have all symbols but no control over the font.

Another note: I did not have the mathalpha package and so edited it out.