# Interactive checkbox that can be ticked or unticked

Tags: ticks

I would like to make checkboxes (preferably on the right edge of the page) for which the viewer of the PDF can tick and untick.

I have found a related [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16000/63024) but the checkbox methods shown there seem to only create static checkboxes. Thank you and I apologize if this is a duplicate.

**Edit**:

What I have done so far is: `\dotfill` and then `$\square$`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You probably want `hyperref`. It can do this although whether or not your reader can check or, even, see the box will depend on their PDF viewer.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! On your suggestion, I'm reading the hyperref manual, but if you have a quick example, I would also really appreciate it. I'll accept it as soon as you post.

Comment: I've posted an example. Although this doesn't show it can be checked, it can. My PDF viewer doesn't deal well with forms and the check doesn't 'stick' so it is hard to take a good screenshot! But it should be fine in `acroread`/Adobe Reader, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a very simple example of a check box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \CheckBox[name=mycheckbox]{This is a check box:}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: A simple checkbox]

See section 6 of the `hyperref` manual for details (PDF and HTML forms). You can configure the appearance etc. in various ways and so on.

## EDIT

`acroread` finally warmed up:

[image: A checked simple checkbox]

Comment: Wonderful. I'll accept when it lets me. Cheers!

Comment: @KimJongUn I've added a screenshot of the checked box. (`acroread` finally warmed up - it spends forever refusing to respond on startup).

Comment: Is there a way to get the checkbox on the left of the text?

Comment: @nukeguy Leave the text blank and write whatever after creating the box? I'm assuming you've looked in the manual and there's no option for this, which is certainly surprising.

Comment: @cfr Yeah, that's what I did.  The problem is that if you do this a lot, you'll have a lot of check boxes with the label " ", and some PDF readers have a problem where it treats all checkboxes of the same label as one checkbox -- if you check one of them, you check all of them.  You can get around this by simply adding [name=....] to all the checkboxes and giving them all different names but I find this somewhat annoying.  As for an option for this... maybe I just missed it, but I couldn't seem to find one, at least not one that was obvious to me.

Comment: @nukeguy There isn't a ready-made option, but you can use the macros explained on page 22 to change the layout, I think. I haven't tested this, but that's what the manual says.