# Using itemize and enumerate at the same time

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I want to have an enumerated list with bullets. So far I've been writing stuff like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a. First
    \item b. Second
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

but a better way to get the enumeration must be possible.

So the question is, is there any list that allows enumerated lists with bullets at the same time? Preferably one that allows setting the bullet for each item, just like itemize.

Comment: Would you complete your code with `\documentclass` `\begin{document}` etc. to make it easier for us to help you?

Comment: @mirkom done. That's the minimal working document of what I want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do that with the `enumerate` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{$\bullet$} a.]
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[{$\bullet$} 1]
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
```

To see more examples just type `texdoc enumerate` on your command prompt to get access to the package documentation.

---

### Edit:

As per the comments below, if you want to change the bullet symbol within the enumerate environment you can use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\mynewitem}[1][]{\refstepcounter{enumi}\item[#1~\theenumi.]}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{$\bullet$} a.]
\mynewitem[\checkmark] Right
\item normal item
\item another normal item
\mynewitem[\checkmark] Right
\mynewitem empty item
\mynewitem[\ding{55}] Wrong!
\item etc.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\mynewitem` accepts every symbol, and the packages `amssymb` and `pifont` are just to get the `\checkmark` and crossed (`\ding{55}`) symbols.

[image: Example of \mynewitem usage]

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. Is there any way I can specify the bullet at the item level? So that I can use different bullet styles throughout the list

Comment: Well, probably yes but the solution won't be as easy as the answer above. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm building a checklist in which each option is enumerated. So I want incorrect answers to have empty boxes and the correct answers to have checked boxes (the boxes and such aren't a problem)

Answer (score 3):

With `enumitem` and some trickery:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16002/4427
\newcommand{\checked}{%
  \mbox{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\checkmark$\hidewidth\cr$\square$\cr}}%
}
\newcommand{\unchecked}{\mbox{$\square$}}

\newenvironment{checkenum}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\checkbox~\alph{*}.,ref=\alph{*},align=left]}
 {\end{enumerate}}
% \checkbox restores the meaning of \currentcheckbox to \unchecked
% after having issued it
\protected\def\checkbox{%
  \currentcheckbox
  \global\let\currentcheckbox\unchecked
}
% \Vitem changes the meaning of \currentcheckbox to \checked
% and issues \item
\newcommand{\Vitem}{%
  \global\let\currentcheckbox\checked\item
}
\let\currentcheckbox\unchecked % initialize

\begin{document}

% the symbols occupy the same space
\checked \unchecked

\unchecked \checked

% the test

\begin{checkenum}
\item Not good
\item Not good
\Vitem Good!
\item Not good
\end{checkenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]