# amssymb: checkmark in a box

Tags: amssymb, bullets

My question is motivated by the `amssymb` package not having a checkmark in a box symbol.
Fortunately, I have found in [Creating Boxed Check Mark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/creating-boxed-check-mark?answertab=active#tab-top) a way to create a checkmark in a box.

However, how to make it compatible with a box with no checkmark? Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{0.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$} A\\
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}{\hspace{0.5em}} B\\

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I am trying to manipulate the parameter in `\hspace` to bring "B" aligned with "A" lacking a precise solution. Can you help?

Comment: you can use `\phantom{\raisebox{0.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}}` instead of the `\hspace{0.5em}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably reversing the logic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\checkbox}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=1
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{0.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}}%
  \fi
  $\square$%
}

\begin{document}

\checkbox{1} A

\checkbox{0} B

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added an argument so there are no issues with spaces after the macro. It's also easier to manage the appearance of the check mark if you so prefer.