# How to center the higher glyph(s) in a `\stackrel` or stretch the lower glyph?

Tags: math-mode, typography, kerning, stacking-symbols

I currently am using a relation

`\newcommand{\Lsense}{\stackrel{\mathbb{L}^1}{=}}`

but unfortunately, the `\mathbb{L}^1` is not nicely centred over the `=` symbol.

[image]

I read some other answers that involve shifting the upper glyph to make it appeared centred, but in this case I think the `\mathbb{L}^1` is wider than the `=`, so maybe I have to "stretch" the `=`?

Alternatively, if someone could explain the code a bit from answers such as from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18446/how-can-i-adjust-the-fine-positioning-of-stackrel), that would be great as I reckon I can just use that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some fine tuning is necessary.

First, we have to remove the small space that TeX adds after superscripts, which is `\scriptspace`. Second, we can compensate the hole due to the conflicting shapes by doing `\mathbb{L}^{\!1}`. Finally, a thin space before the “L” helps in centering. The whole thing is set in `\mathclap`, so it won't count for the width of the big symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}

\newcommand{\Lsense}{%
  \overset{\mathclap{\,\mathbb{L}^{\!1}\kern-\scriptspace}}{=}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\Lsense B$

$A=B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The distance from the left side of the “L” to the left side of “=” is not the same as the distance from the right side of the “1” to the right side of the “=”, but it's not of a concern, visually, because the exponent is set quite high. You may want to use `\mspace{2mu}` (or less) instead of `\,` (which would be `\mspace{3mu}`).

Here's a “boxed” version that shows the horizontal size is the same.

[image]

Comment: I chose this as the answer because it compensates for the superscript and the left-alignment of the L. :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Lsense}{\stackrel{\mathbb{L}^{\mkern-5mu 1}}{=}} %precise value up to you

$A\Lsense B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Certainly, `\mkern` can be also in other places, e.g.,

```
\newcommand{\Lsense}{\stackrel{\mkern2mu\mathbb{L}^{\mkern-5mu 1}}{=}}
```

Comment: How does `mkern` work? It moves the following character `XXmu` left/right? Is it part of `amssymb`?

Comment: It definitely looks better than what I had in any case! :)

Comment: @jamesh625 It is TeX primitive, so it doesn't need any packages. And it adds an unshrinkable space (kern). In math mode small length units called `mu` are suggested.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand*\Lsense{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\mathbb{L}^{\mathrlap{\!1}}}{=}}
```

You can remove `\scripscriptstyle` if you think it's to small. The `\mathrlap` is key here, because makes the superscript take zero space.