# Overlaying two symbols

Tags: symbols, lyx, kerning

I use LyX, so a lot of the working is hidden from me.
I want to overlay the symbols `\star` and `\bigcircle`.

How do I do this?
I know it can be done, ad there is the `\not`, which works like that

Comment: I don't think that LyX provides some UI for that. See e.g. [Overlay symbol with another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another) for ideas how to do this using TeX code.

Comment: Also `\not` is an own symbol and not an overlay.

Comment: what package is providing the `\start` and `\Bigcircle` symbols? There's no mention of them in the *Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list*

Comment: sorry Typos. I meant \star and \bigcircle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to teach this to LyX, but here's how I would do it:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\circledstar}{\text{\textcircled{$\star$}}}
```