# The line produced by \not looks bad on wider symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols

When using `\not` together with wider symbols such as `\Leftrightarrow` the diagonal line produced by `\not` is placed too far to the left. How can the line be properly aligned?

For example the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\(\not\subset\)% Looks good

\(\not\approx\)% Looks good

\(\not\leftrightarrow\)% \not line is too far to the left

\(\not\Leftrightarrow\)% \not line is too far to the left

\end{document}
```

produces the following output where the last two symbols has got a misaligned diagonal line

[image: Aligned and not aligned examples of \not]

Also, maybe the lines may need other changes than alignment to look good.

Comment: You could try to place it over it by yourself. See the answers to [Overlay symbol with another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another). Note that the accepted answer (written by me) seems not the best way to go after all. Check the other answers first.

Comment: @Martin It doesn't work because `\not` has zero width.

Comment: @egreg: I knew that. IMHO this makes it more difficult but not impossible. I still thought pointing that question out added some value. I'm not saying it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\not` symbol typesets a zero width character which protrudes on the right and so it is apt to be superimposed only on certain characters having a suitable width (the equal sign, for example); since the two arrows are wider than the equal sign, the alignment is not optimal. A solution is to push the `\not` a bit on the right and backspacing for the same amount:

```
\newcommand\nleftrightarrow{
  \mathrel{\mkern2.1mu\not\mkern-2.1mu\leftrightarrow}}
\newcommand\nLeftrightarrow{
  \mathrel{\mkern2.1mu\not\mkern-2.1mu\Leftrightarrow}}
```

You might also consider the set of "negated arrows" provided by **amssymb**; the names are the same that I chose:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}

$X\nleftrightarrow Y$ and $X\nLeftrightarrow Y$
```

Try both and choose what suits your taste. If you already load **amssymb** use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

[image]

One can also define a `\xnot` command that gives to the symbol the width of the equal sign and use a standard method for superimposing symbols:

```
\newcommand\xnot{\mathpalette\xxnot}
\newcommand*\xxnot[2]{\mathrel{\ooalign{%
  \hfil$#1\not\mathrel{\hphantom=}$\hfil\cr\hfil$#1#2$\hfil\cr}}}
```

Now `\xnot\leftrightarrow` gives the same result as the "definition by hand" before. The strange `\mathrel` after `\not` has its explanation in the fact that TeX never adds space between two relation math atoms. Thanks to Martin for having suggested this method. The **centernot** package does something similar.

Comment: I appreciate the detail of this answer. I like both the shorter lines of amssymb and the longer of your definition by hand. Is there any convention to look at in choosing which to use?

Comment: @N.N. I would prefer the AMS ones, had I to use negated arrows, which I don't like at all. :)

Answer (score 11):

The [`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) package provides a centered slash with the `\centernot` macro, which looks far better than the original `\not` in many cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}
\begin{document}
    $\centernot\leftrightarrow$, $\centernot\Leftrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

## Result:

[image: \centernot\leftrightarrow], [image: \centernot\Leftrightarrow]

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer (and the resulting output).

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`cancel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package for arrows and other wider expressions:

```
\usepackage{cancel}

\(\cancel\leftrightarrow\)
\(\cancel\Leftrightarrow\)
```

[image: cancelled arrows]

Comment: If I want a somewhat uniform look of `\neq` and wider canceled symbols this solution will be unsatisfactory. For example, compare the output of `\neq` and `\cancel\Leftrightarrow`, the line of the latter is distinctly different.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you only need `\not\Leftrightarrow` (or a few other similar symbols), these are already included with prefix `n`: So just use `\nLeftrightarrow`, `\nleq`, etc.

(of course, `centernot` or `cancel` are still useful for all the other symbols that do not support this)