# The \not rendering and the line over sigma symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am writing a paper and I need to use the `\not` command on `\sigma` which stands for a order relation on a set. The issue is that the line over the sigma symbol is rendered poorly, is there any way I am not aware of so that the exact symbol I need is displayed correctly?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. You can draw it in detexify for both checking the symbol and also having a snapshot of what you wanted to post here.

Comment: Crossing out a letter is IMHO a very ugly thing to do.

Comment: @tohecz it's how my professor "named" the order relation, there isn't any I can do about it.

Comment: @percusse tried to edit the post, but the site throws me back a server error, but I'll keep in mind for next questions I might ask, thank you.

Comment: Related: [The line produced by `\not` looks bad on wider symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23469/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot
\begin{document}
$\not\sigma\ \centernot\sigma$
\end{document}
```