# How to write a pretty \not \varepsilon

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

How can I write a pretty `\not\varepsilon`? I want something like `\notin`, since I use `\varepsilon` as a relation symbol like `\in`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [The line produced by `\not` looks bad on wider symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23469/5764)

Comment: @Werner it's more or less a dual rather than a duplicate (epsilon is too narrow rather than too wide) but the issue (and the posted answers) are the same...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since `\varepsilon` has a smaller width than `=`, the alignment with `\not` is not perfect. `\not` is optimized for `=`. Package `centernot` helps to center the `\not` a little better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}
\[ a \not\mathrel{\varepsilon} b \]
\[ a \centernot\varepsilon b \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

You can just juggle with the spacing a bit I'm not sure it classifies as pretty though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\noteps{\mathrel{\!\not\mathrel{\,\varepsilon\!}\,}}

\begin{document}

$a \notin b \noteps c$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm nor sure if it is pretty, but...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\nwe{\mathrel{\not\mskip-\thinmuskip\varepsilon}}

$a \nwe A$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]