# How to negate a specific symbol?

Tags: symbols

I want to negate the symbol whose code is `\models` (this would be specific to Formal Logic). How can I do that? I tried a number of combination, but didn't find how this could be done. I tried `\neqmodels`, `\nemodels`, `\notmodels`, `\nmodels`  but all of them are wrong.

Is there a general way to negate symbols?

Comment: Does `\not\models` work for you?

Comment: @ScottH. , Oh this works! thanx! but is there a general rule to negate symbols ?

Comment: There may be other ways, but all I know for a general rule is to throw a `\not` in front of they symbol to be negated.

Comment: There are a couple of good answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23469/the-line-produced-by-not-looks-bad-on-wider-symbols/) that might be adapted if you don't like the looks of `\not`.

Comment: @ScottH.: Perhaps we can generalize this question into something that requests the negation of a symbol (the question as well), and write up something that uses a bunch of methods. `\cancel`, `\not`, and more?

Comment: @Werner  I think it's a great idea to have a canonical answer for this type of question.  I'm not well versed in this sort of stuff however, so couldn't provide the kind of answer required.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve the negation of a symbol:

1. Follow the guidelines in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764) to see whether such a symbol already exists.

   This is usually the best course of action, since the symbol would have been constructed to match certain specification (say, placement and height/depth of negation symbol). If such a symbol is only available in a different font, then consider including only that symbol by following the instructions in [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764).

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
   \begin{document}
   \[
     a \neq b \nparallel c \nvDash d \nprec e
   \]
   \end{document}
   ```
2. For a symbol `\mysymbol`, try `\not\mysymbol`. `\not` is a zero-width math relation that is set "on the right" of where it's called. As such, it visually overlaps the typical math relation/symbol. Not always perfect, but works in general.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
   \[
     a \not= b \not\geq c \not\sim d \not\approx e \not\in f
   \]
   \end{document}
   ```
3. [`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) works well when symbols are somewhat wider than usual, yet you still want the regular `\not`-like visual.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{centernot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot
   \begin{document}
   \[
     a \not= b \centernot= c 
       \not\parallel d \centernot\parallel e 
       \not\longrightarrow f \centernot\longrightarrow g
   \]
   \end{document}
   ```
4. The [`cancel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) draws a diagonal line across a symbol to "cancel" it.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{centernot,cancel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{centernot,cancel}
   \begin{document}
   \[
     a \not= b \centernot= c \mathrel{\cancel{=}} d
       \not\longrightarrow e \centernot\longrightarrow f \mathrel{\cancel{\longrightarrow}} g
   \]
   \end{document}
   ```
5. Other methods include using graphics packages like [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) to draw rules in specific locations across a symbol/construction.

Comment: This is a great answer :) thanx for editing the question and providing this answer , it's a reference , I think!

Comment: `\not\in` shows why `\notin` is defined

Comment: Point 2 works, including "\not\in". Thanks.
Kindly try $\not\in  \qquad \in $ with proper latex package.

Answer (score 10):

A good compromise is usually `\centernot` (from the package `centernot`).

But sometimes `\centernot` is good, sometimes it isn't. For instance, `\centernot{\in}` produces a poorer result than `\notin` that uses the common slash instead.

In other cases, some small adjustments are necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}

$\centernot{\eta}$

$\mkern-1mu\not\mathrel{\mkern1mu\eta}\mkern1mu$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first `\mkern` does a small backing up; then `\not` is typeset, which takes *no* horizontal space, then `\eta` is printed with *no* intervening space, because it has been turned into a relation symbol and TeX adds no space between consecutive relation symbols, but preceded by a small space that compensates for the negative space inserted before. A final space is added to take care of the fact that the slash ends right of `\eta`.

Note that all the construction will be considered as a relation symbol as far as spacing is concerned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\noteta}{%
  \mkern-1mu\not\mathrel{\mkern1mu\eta}\mkern1mu
}

\begin{document}

$A \noteta B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If an ordinary symbol is desired, add `\mathord` or just a pair of additional braces:

```
\newcommand{\noteta}{%
  \mathord{\mkern-1mu\not\mathrel{\mkern1mu\eta}\mkern1mu}%
}
```

is equivalent to, but clearer than,

```
\newcommand{\noteta}{%
  {\mkern-1mu\not\mathrel{\mkern1mu\eta}\mkern1mu}%
}
```

Such manual adjustments may be needed depending on the shape of the symbols involved.

Answer (score -1):

> How to get `\not\to` arrow?

### Probably best test code with *amssymb*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths

\begin{document}
$\nrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

### Test code with *centernot* package but negative complications with *unicode-math*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot

\begin{document}
\[
\centernot\to
\]
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

Errors with *centernot* package

- with *unicode-math*: *Latex Error: ./file.tex:9 Missing { inserted.*

### *\not\to* alone gives unaligned arrow but *unicode-math* package works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths
\begin{document}
$\not\to$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question about this subject was closed as duplicate. If you change the question to reflect the *actual* problem you have, then it can be reopened. Making a question here is not the way to go.

Comment: @egreg This is not a question! It is an answer to the thing. This is a specific task to negate `\to` symbol. I already deleted the old question because it was closed. I think this one is here ok because it fits the title.

Comment: You do seem to answer a different question to what was asked though. Especially when referring to `\nrightarrow` which is not necessarily present for all symbols. And `centernot` was already covered by  Werner and egreg. I fell you could re-work this answer quite a bit and it would be OK. You would have to make it more general. Your first point could be to try and find a negated version of the symbol (often called `\n...`), of course here the OP already tried that.

Comment: `\centernot` was not covered for the symbol `\to`. It is the case here. Therefore, I left it like that. Feel free to edit if you can improve it, but without losing the information about `\to` and its negation.

Comment: Mhhh, but then there are other symbols that are not explicitly covered in the other answers, do you want to add an answer for those as well? I appreciate that there was some lateral thinking needed to get from `\to` to `\rightarrow` and then to `\nrightarrow` as a negated version of `\not`. But from the other answer people can easily infer that trying `\centernot\to` might be an option.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to those too. This question is coming first in the google when you search `\not\to` and relevant words. So yes, I think we should add here much more about negating symbols than currently; about complications, for instance, which are not covered enough fully here.