# Not much greater than sign

Tags: math-mode, relation-symbols

I am trying to make the negation of the `$\gg$` sign in latex. I believe that it exists since It is on my homework sheet that appears to be typed in latex. I tried to draw the sign in detexify, but it did not give me anything. I also tried searching some tables of binary relation signs for latex but I could not find anything.

Thanks for the help,
Gabe

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I think `\not\gg` will do what you desire.

Comment: See [How to negate a specific symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996/5764)