# Error With Inequality

Tags: math-mode

I typed the following and get an error. Help would be appreciated it. `$x^{2}\lneq x$` It states undefined control sequence.

Comment: you need to have `\usepackage{amssymb}` in your preamble.  that's where the name is defined; the symbol is included in the `amsfonts`.

Comment: Welcome! It is obvious in this case, but always include the exact error message - *which* control sequence is undefined?

Comment: Related: [How to negate a specific symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996/5764)

Answer (score 2):

you need to have `\usepackage{amssymb}` in your preamble.

that's where the name `\lneq` is defined; the symbol is included in the `amsfonts`.