# How can I use \not with more than one symbol?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

[image]

When using `\not` in math mode only the following symbol gets crossed, is there any way to apply it to more than one symbol evenly as if it were one operator?

I tried `\not{<:}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to negate a specific symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996/5764)

Comment: `\not` is just symbol, its bounding box has zero width and the symbol is actually to the right of that box by an amount designed to place in top of many following symbols.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\mathclap` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lecolon}{<:}

\begin{document}
\[ \not\mathclap\lecolon \]
%your whole expression should be something like
\[ \gamma\not\mathclap\lecolon\mkern10mu\tau \]
\end{document}
```

[image: example_rendered]

Anyways, I think your expression looks more like the `\not` reffers only to the less sign and it's followed by a colon:

```
\[ \gamma\not\mathclap<:\tau \]
```

[image: example2_rendered]

which can finally be slightly refined to

```
\[ \gamma\mkern-2mu\not\mkern2mu\mathclap<:\tau \]
```

[image: example3_output]

Comment: Note, of course, that the `\mathclap` totally kills the width of its contents, so if you're using `\not\mathclap\iff` or some other longer symbol then you'll need to adjust your `\mkern`s. (Also, you should consider using mathtools's `<\vcentcolon` instead of `<:` .)

Answer (score 10):

Here my MWE. What do you prefer?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{centernot,cancel}

\begin{document}

\[
  \cancel{<:} ~~~~\text{or}~~~~ \centernot{<:}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Choose a more representative name of what you are talking about with that symbol. Note that the standard is to use `\n<relation name>` to show the negated symbol of `\<relation name>`, so you may want to adhere to that.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{centernot,amssymb,mathtools}

\newcommand*\somekindofrelation{\mathrel{<:}}
\newcommand*\nsomekindofrelation{\mathrel{\centernot{<}\vcentcolon}}

\begin{document}

\[ \gamma \nsomekindofrelation \tau \]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Result:

[image]