# Symbol for negated exclamation mark

Tags: symbols

I need a symbol as an exclamation mark, on which a negation sign exists:

[image]

I've just checked [The Comprehensive Latex Symbol List](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPx-n-_o3UAhVB7YMKHX1vAL4QFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftug.ctan.org%2Finfo%2Fsymbols%2Fcomprehensive%2Fsymbols-a4.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGCQeIwjbEo-cV_eZX4g9Aze09VNQ&sig2=ulm24Et4bb8kKZtE2MSLPQ) to find something useful but all I've found are the negation symbols of Pages 49-57, where there is no symbol like what I need.

Comment: Text mode or math mode?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Math mode.

Comment: Has `$\not{!}$` a too long slash?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Unfortunately, Yes. It's a little bit ugly and even unreadable.

Comment: The slash has to be tilted?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes. Pretty similar to the other negated relation symbols.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to negate a specific symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996/5764)

Comment: What does it mean / what is the use?

Comment: @cat: In the supervisory control theory of discrete event systems, if there exists an event $$\sigma$$ eligible to occur from the state $$q$$, we say $$\delta(q,\sigma)!$$, i.e., the transition is defined. Conversely, if such transition does not exist, one puts a struck on the $$!$$ to reflect the negation.

Comment: @Roboticist Now, if there were ever a domains-specific, niche application, that's it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about this with `stackengine`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\myexc}{\mathrel{\topinset{\rotatebox{-45}{\scalebox{.5}{/}}}{!}{}{}}}
\newcommand{\stevexc}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{}{\rotatebox{-45}{\scalebox{.5}{$/$}}}{$!$}}}
\newcommand{\steveyc}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{.15ex}{\scalebox{1.5}[.4]{$/$}}{$!$}}}

\begin{document}
    My original answer:
    \[
    A \myexc B
    \]

    A more correct solution (see Stevens's comment):
    \[
    A \stevexc B
    \]

    Steven's elegant solution without \verb|\rotatebox|:
    \[
    A \steveyc B
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your reputation just keeps "stacking" up! `;^)`

Comment: I was one of the first to upvote.  The other approach I considered was a `\scalebox{}[]{/}`, with skewed vertical/horizontal magnifications.  You might be able to avoid rotating it as such.

Comment: I note you did the stack in text mode, which could bite you depending on the font.  The use of an inset automatically applied `\useanchorwidth`, which is good, though `\topinset` is deprecated towards, instead, the use of `\stackinset`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I didn't manage to get the correct symbol with only `\scalebox{}[]{/}`. Please look at the `\stevexc` command and tell me if I correctly understood your suggestion!

Comment: Yes, you transitioned to `\stackinset` properly, and employed it in math mode.  I will try to see if I can do anything with my `\scalebox` suggestion.

Comment: Here is what I had in mind: `\newcommand{\steveyc}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{t}{.15ex}{\scalebox{1.5}[.4]{$/$}}{$!$}}}`  No rotation required.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Foolishly, I didn't think to increase the horizontal scaling. I've just added your solution to my answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: if your stackengines make enough stacks then maybe you can stack exchange?

Comment: @cat LOL! `stackengine` is not mine, it's Steven's. But is your code a catcode?

Comment: Dear @CarLaTeX, is it possible to make the slanted line a bit shorter, similar to its size in `\nmid`?

Comment: @Arrow See egreg's answer, I think it's better than mine,

Answer (score 13):

This might appeal to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\smallslash}{\mathord}{operators}{32}
\newcommand{\negexcl}{\mathrel{\smallslash\mkern-5mu{!}}}

\begin{document}

$a\negexcl b$

$a\mathrel{!}b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation, with the slash similar to `\nmid`. The first line shows that the two slashes coincide. The `color` package is only used for that example.

The symbol won't change according to the math style. It's left as an exercise to adapt it for subscripts and superscripts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,pict2e,picture}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\negexcl}{\mathrel{\smallslash{!}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallslash}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\mkern1mu$}%
  \dimen@=\wd\z@
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
  \roundcap
  \put(0,\fontdimen22\textfont2){\line(1,0.9){5\dimen@}}
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\ooalign{\color{red}$\negexcl$\cr$\nmid$\cr}}
{\ooalign{$\nmid$\cr\color{red}$\negexcl$\cr}}

$a\negexcl b\nmid c$

$a\mathrel{!}b\mid c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: @Roboticist You were too fast accepting my answer, please feel free to change your choice!

Comment: Dear @egreg, is it possible to have the slanted line with the same proportions as in `\nmid`? I mean the slope, length, and width. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Arrow Do you like the new version?

Comment: @egreg it's perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @egreg it's bit strange, but no LyX document will compile for me when it contains the `newcommand` block.

Comment: @Arrow Just don't use LyX, then, it's easier. ;-) Maybe it's the fault of the missing `\makeatletter` that I forgot to add.

Comment: @egreg that fixed it :) I'll try figuring out how to make it look perfect as a sub/superscript. Thanks again.