# What is the LaTeX symbol for "forking independent" (model theory)?

Tags: symbols, logic

I am looking for a way to set the symbol for "forking independent" (for example, see "Essential Stability Theory", Steven Buechler, p.217). It looks a bit like an anchor or an upside-down 'T' with a curved bar.

[image]

Comment: Depending on your accent, I imagine that 'forking independent' can sometimes sound quite different than its intended meaning :)

Answer (score 27):

I don't think this symbol exists in any of the typical packages, so it looks like you'll have to roll your own. You can combine the `\smile` symbol from the `amssymb` package with a `\vert` line for this. Here's one way to do it, based on [Overlay symbol with another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another) and [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\def\forkindep{\mathrel{\raise0.2ex\hbox{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\vert$\hidewidth\cr\raise-0.9ex\hbox{$\smile$}}}}}

\begin{document}
The symbol by itself: $\forkindep$

The symbol used with \verb|\underset|: $A \underset{C}{\forkindep} B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner: Don't assume that I haven't tried to find the symbol in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List and Detexify couldn't figure out my doodles either. I am not saying that I haven't missed something but I definitely tried to look it up. Jake: Thank you so much! That will work for me. I would accept your answer but I lost my cookie. Sorry. *edit: converted to comment*

Comment: You can register your account, and a moderator will merge that account with these unregistered ones, so you'll regain ownership of the question.

Comment: An improvement would be to use the starred version of `DeclareMathOp`, which undersets subscripts automatically, i.e. `\DeclareMathOperator*{\forkindep}{\raise0.2ex\hbox{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\vert$\hidewidth\cr\raise-0.9ex\hbox{$\smile$}}}}` will allow you to get the desired result when `\forkindep_C` is used.

Comment: @merryman: I merged your two accounts and converted your answer into a comment.

Comment: No, `\DeclareMathOperator` is wrong here: this seems to be a relation symbol.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I've rolled back to the old version.

Answer (score 18):

A variation, using `\oalign` instead of `\ooalign`; the spacing will be right only if the symbol is treated as a binary relation

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\forkindep}[1][]{%
  \mathrel{
    \mathop{
      \vcenter{
        \hbox{\oalign{\noalign{\kern-.3ex}\hfil$\vert$\hfil\cr
              \noalign{\kern-.7ex}
              $\smile$\cr\noalign{\kern-.3ex}}}
      }
    }\displaylimits_{#1}
  }
}

\begin{document}
$A\forkindep[C]B$
\[
A\forkindep[C]B
\]
\end{document}
```

This will typeset the (optional) argument as a subscript in text style and below the symbol in display style.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Unicode has that symbol at `0x2ADD`, so you could do with XeTeX something like:

```
\XeTeXmathchardef\nonforking"3"2"2ADD
% ^take from symbol family ("2), and define as relation ("3)
$ A \nonforking_C B $
$\displaystyle A \mathop{\nonforking}_C B $ % note: changed from rel to op
```

[image]

This would of course need the appropriate fonts and such loaded (with `unicode-math` for example, it is already defined as `\forksnot`)

Comment: ...it defines `\forksnot`... really?

Comment: @Werner: [Seems to me](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/blob/master/unicode-math-table.tex)

Comment: My comment was more tongue-in-cheek, since it resembles `\forksnot` ~ `fork-snot` rather than `forks-not`, which might just as well have been written `\notforks`. Perhaps I should retrieve my mind from the gutter.

Comment: @Werner: hehe, there seemed to be *something* off with the command name, but I couldn't quite put my finger on it. Uhh.. “put my finger on a forkful of snot” sounds *so* **wrong**

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to the [arXiv](http://www.arxiv.org), one can find out what Buechler himself has used (and other model theorists in the area).  Downloading the source of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101036) and looking in its preamble, one finds:

```
\def\dnfo{\;\raise.2em\hbox{$\mathrel|\kern-.9em\lower.4em\hbox{$\smile$}$}}

\def\dnf#1{\lower.9em\hbox{$\buildrel\dnfo\over{ \scriptstyle  #1}$}}

\def\indep#1#2#3{\hbox{\mathsurround=0pt$#1 \  \dnf{#2} \ #3$}}
```

(among several related definitions).  Then `\indep{A}{C}{B}` produces your example.

Comment: Not what I would call good TeX programming.

Comment: Still, +1 for going to the source.

Comment: @egreg: agreed — I considered adding a disclaimer along the lines of “…but the definitions suggested in other answers are rather nicer”, but then decided that was sufficiently self-evident :-)

Answer (score 4):

Including the package `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` you can also use `\downfree` (or `\ndownfree` respectively if you want to talk about dependent sets) for the desired symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not the most beautiful TeX code, but the following produces a beautiful nonforking symbol (`$A \ind_C B$`) and an even more beautiful placement of the slash in the forking symbol (`$A \nind_C B$`).

```
\def\Ind#1#2{#1\setbox0=\hbox{$#1x$}\kern\wd0\hbox to 0pt{\hss$#1\mid$\hss}
\lower.9\ht0\hbox to 0pt{\hss$#1\smile$\hss}\kern\wd0}

\def\ind{\mathop{\mathpalette\Ind{}}}

\def\notind#1#2{#1\setbox0=\hbox{$#1x$}\kern\wd0
\hbox to 0pt{\mathchardef\nn=12854\hss$#1\nn$\kern1.4\wd0\hss}
\hbox to 0pt{\hss$#1\mid$\hss}\lower.9\ht0 \hbox to 0pt{\hss$#1\smile$\hss}\kern\wd0}

\def\nind{\mathop{\mathpalette\notind{}}}
```

[image][image]

This was passed along to me by Greg Cousins, who got it from Martin Bays, who got it from Rahim Moosa, and you'd have to ask Rahim about the original source.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)