# Modifying the symbol for non-forking

Tags: symbols

I want to modify the following lines of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\def\forkindep{\mathrel{\raise0.2ex\hbox{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\vert^{d}$\hidewidth\cr\raise-0.9ex\hbox{$\smile$}}}}}

 \begin{document}
 $A \underset{C}{\forkindep}B$
 \end{document}
```

found in [What is the LaTeX symbol for "forking independent" (model theory)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42093/what-is-the-latex-symbol-for-forking-independent-model-theory) to have a line followed by a prime symbol (i.e. |') in the forking independence relation.  I attempted to do this by changing the `$\vert$` to `$\vert^{'}$`. However this cause the line segment to not align properly with the smile symbol (I want the line segment bisect the smile, but it is a little to the left the command). I was wondering how I could fix this issue.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you should be able to treat the prime as having no width; try $\vert\rlap{{}^\prime}$.  (you may have to invoke math mode inside the `\rlap`, as `\rlap{${}^\prime$}`; (i'm not in a position to test at the moment).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That didn't work. It ended up pushing the line even more to the left.

Comment: Try `\llap` ? It would be much easier if you posted a complete minimal example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm sorry. You suggestion worked! I had changed the code a bit, trying to get it to work and didn't realize till now. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @Andrew. Thank you. I didn't understand what cfr meant when they said that I should post a complete minimal example. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer a variant of my solution to the problem of the linked question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\forkindep}[1][]{%
  \mathrel{
    \mathop{
      \vcenter{
        \hbox{\oalign{\noalign{\kern-.3ex}\hfil$\vert$\hfil\cr
              \noalign{\kern-.7ex}
              $\smile$\cr\noalign{\kern-.3ex}}}
      }
    }\displaylimits_{#1}
  }
}
\newcommand{\nonforkindep}[1][]{%
  \mathrel{
    \mathop{
      \vcenter{
        \hbox{\oalign{\noalign{\kern-.3ex}\hfil$\vert$\rlap{$'$}\hfil\cr
              \noalign{\kern-.7ex}
              $\smile$\cr\noalign{\kern-.3ex}}}
      }
    }\displaylimits_{#1}
  }
}

\begin{document}
$A\forkindep[C]B$ $A\nonforkindep[C]B$
\[
A\forkindep[C]B\quad A\nonforkindep[C]B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]