# How do I generate a symbol that is like ː (\textlengthmark) with a small circle exactly in the middle?

Tags: symbols

I would like to generate a symbol that is `tipa`'s `\textlengthmark` with a small circle overlaid perfectly in the middle, so that the symbol has vertical and horizontal symmetry.

How do I do this? (I have a suspicion that `tikz` will help, but I am not sure whether this machinery is really needed.)

Some clarifications:

- The symbol should scale to arbitrary sizes. (I am using `anyfontsize`.)
- The circle should be small, that is I *don't* want `\text{\textcircled{\(\Utextlengthmark\)}}` (with an enclosing circle).
- There are a couple of similar questions here, but the point is that I don't want to have to manually adjust the vertical alignment. There should be a way of having TeX automatically match their horizontal *and* vertical centers. Also, if I use a manual shift amount for a `\raisebox`, that's not gonna work in a subscript context etc. (I never figured out how to get manually scaled and shifted symbols to automatically "work" in subscripts.)

---

The following code (adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12900/14996))

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[noenc,safe]{tipa}

\def\typeC{\mathrel{%
    \mathchoice{\TYPEC}{\TYPEC}{\scriptsize\TYPEC}{\tiny\TYPEC}%
}}
\def\TYPEC{{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\textlengthmark}%
    \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss\(\circ\)\hss}}\box0
}}

\begin{document}

\(\typeC + S_{\typeC}\)

\end{document}
```

has two problems:

- The `\circ` is too large; about half the size would be desired.
- The `\circ` is not vertically centered.

Comment: Did you already tried the general questions about math symbols: [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/2975) and [Overlay symbol with another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12895/2975)?

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yes, very much exhaustively. | Yes; see my edit.

Comment: @MartinScharrer There are two things to keep in mind: 1. If I do a manual `\raisebox`-adjustment, that in my experience does not scale right (in a subscript, footnote, ... context). 2. It should be possible to have the centering be performed automatically. What's more, both symbols have perfect horizontal and vertical symmetry.

Comment: @LoverofStructure The raisebox is not an issue if you use fontsize-dependent lengths, i.e. `em` or `ex`. The only issue is the scaling. I tried with the `relsize` package, but get stuck on very small sizes (incl. sub- and superscripts). FYI, here is my code: `\renewcommand{\RSsmallest}{1pt}` and `\def\TYPEC{{\setbox0\hbox{\textlengthmark}\rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss\raisebox{0.11ex{\smaller[2]\textopenbullet}\hss}}\box0}}`

Comment: @Xavier I often scale with `\scalefont` for precise results, and I simply haven't figured out how to adapt such scaling for superscripts etc automatically.

Comment: @Xavier I was trying out your code, but my system doesn't know `\RSsmallest`. How can I make it work/compile?

Comment: You need to load the `relsize` package. But Heiko's answer below seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @Xavier I tried it with `relsize`, but it doesn't compile. I think something about the parentheses in your posted code doesn't match up. Could you check again? Also it might be worth an answer, despite Heiko already having posted one.

Comment: @LoverofStructure There was indeed a closing brace missing after the `0.11ex` :(  I've posted the code and result [here](http://ge.tt/1gPeyCZ). I don't think it's worth an answer, as it doesn't work for small size as I wrote earlier

Comment: @Xavier Could you post your correction in a comment here? Also, it's okay on TeX.SE if an answer merely adds additional information (even though it's unlikely to be accepted as the chosen/right answer), so posting it as an answer is fine (and will get my upvote).

Comment: @LoverofStructure Sure, here it is: `\def\TYPEC{{\setbox0\hbox{\textlengthmark}\rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss\raisebox{0.11ex}{\smaller[2]\textopenbullet}\hss}}\box0}}`

Comment: @Xavier   
This `\documentclass{memoir} \usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[noenc,safe]{tipa} \usepackage{relsize} \renewcommand{\RSsmallest}{1pt} \def\typeC{\mathrel{\mathchoice{\TYPEC}{\TYPEC}{\scriptsize\TYPEC}{\tiny\TYPEC}}‌​} \def\TYPEC{{\setbox0\hbox{\textlengthmark}\rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss\raisebox{0.11ex}{\smaller[2]\textopenbullet}\hss}}\box0}} \begin{document} \(\typeC + S_{\typeC}\) \end{document}` still doesn't compile ...

Comment: @LoverofStructure You need `textcomp` for `\textopenbullet`. My full tex file is [here](http://ge.tt/1gPeyCZ).

Comment: @Xavier Great! It looks like adding `textcomp` to my code does the trick; `calc` (from your source code) is not needed, though.

Comment: @LoverofStructure No indeed. I originally used `calc` to calculate the raise offset as `0.5\height-0.5\ht0`, which didn't give perfect results for some reason I don't get...

Comment: @LoverofStructure Well, Heiko just found out why. I checked the depth of the elements, but didn't suspect a wrong bounding box and learned something new. This long chat finally paid off :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following solution constructs the symbol from `\textlengthmark` and `\circ`. The latter symbol `\circ` is vertically centered to the current math axis. First the middle of `\circ` is moved to the base line, then it is scaled down to 28 percent of the height of `\textlengthmark`. Then the resized circle is moved to the middle of `\textlengthmark`. `\text` is needed for resizing the text symbol `\textlengthmark` according to the current math style. `\mathpalette` is used to construct the symbol for the current math style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amstext}% or amsmath
\usepackage{graphicx}% or graphics

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\circlengthmark}{%
  {\CircLengthMarkAux}%
  % curly braces allow the use of the symbol after ^ or _ without braces
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\CircLengthMarkAux}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathpalette\@CircLengthMarkAux{\text{\textlengthmark}}%
  }%
}
\newsavebox\clm@boxa
\newsavebox\clm@boxb
\newcommand*{\@CircLengthMarkAux}[2]{%
  % #1 contains one of \displaystyle, \textstyle,
  %    \scriptstyle or \scriptscriptstyle
  % #2 contains the length mark symbol
  \sbox\clm@boxa{$\m@th#1#2$}% \textlengthmark
  \sbox\clm@boxb{$#1\vcenter{}$}% math axis
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \kern.5\wd\clm@boxa
    \hss
    \raise.5\ht\clm@boxa\hbox{%
      \resizebox{!}{.14\ht\clm@boxa}{% adopt the factor to your needs
        \lower\ht\clm@boxb\hbox{$\m@th#1\circ$}%
      }%
    }%
    \hss
    \kern-.5\wd\clm@boxa
  }%
  \usebox\clm@boxa
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Symbol: \circlengthmark (\textlengthmark)
$\circlengthmark^{\circlengthmark^\circlengthmark}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Update: More perfection

With higher magnification values the circle is not perfectly centered, it
is a tiny bit too low. The reason is the character bounding box of
`\textlengthmark`. Its upper and lower bounds are too small by asymmetric amounts:

```
\documentclass[border=.1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.02pt}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\color{red}\textlengthmark}%
\fbox{\textcolor{red}{\raisebox{0pt}[1.025\height][0.02\height]{\textlengthmark}}}%
\fbox{\color{red}$\circ$}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Char boxes]

The middle symbol compensates by enlarging the height and depth.

```
\documentclass[border=.1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\circlengthmark}{%
  {\CircLengthMarkAux}%
  % curly braces allow the use of the symbol after ^ or _ without braces
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\CircLengthMarkAux}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathpalette\@CircLengthMarkAux{\text{\textlengthmark}}%
  }%
}
\newsavebox\clm@boxa
\newsavebox\clm@boxb
\newcommand*{\@CircLengthMarkAux}[2]{%
  % #1 contains one of \displaystyle, \textstyle,
  %    \scriptstyle or \scriptscriptstyle
  % #2 contains the length mark symbol
  \sbox\clm@boxa{%
    % \textlengthmark with fix of character bounding box
    \raisebox{0pt}[1.025\height][.02\height]{%
      $\m@th#1#2$%
    }%
  }%
  \sbox\clm@boxb{$#1\vcenter{}$}% math axis
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \kern.5\wd\clm@boxa
    \hss
    \dimen@=.5\ht\clm@boxa
    \advance\dimen@ by -.5\dp\clm@boxa
    \raise\dimen@\hbox{%
      \resizebox{!}{.14\ht\clm@boxa}{% adopt the factor to your needs
        \lower\ht\clm@boxb\hbox{$\m@th#1\circ$}%
      }%
    }%
    \hss
    \kern-.5\wd\clm@boxa
  }%
  \usebox\clm@boxa
}
\makeatother

% for testing
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.02pt}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\color{red}\circlengthmark}%
\textsuperscript{\fbox{\color{red}\circlengthmark}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with fix of character bounding box]

For greater perfection, both `\textlengthmark` and the circled symbol need to be replaced by a better font or drawn from scratch (e.g. `tikz`).