# \bot like symbol with two horizontal lines

Tags: symbols

I'm searching for a symbol that looks like \bot, but with two horizontal lines on the bottom. Roughly like this:

```
     |
     |
     |
 =========
```

I couldn't find anything with detexify, and I've tried rotating a \Vdash but the spacing between the two parallel lines seems too big. I'd like to use the symbol in math mode, both as an operator and as a superscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superimpose a clipped raised `\bot` to `\bot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Bot}{%
  \mathord{\vphantom{\bot}\mathpalette\mich@Bot\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\mich@Bot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\bot$\cr
    \clipbox*{0pt 0pt {\width} {.5\height}}{\raisebox{.2\height}{$\m@th#1\bot$}}\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\Bot \bot$

$\scriptstyle \Bot \bot$

$\scriptscriptstyle \Bot \bot$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the package `MnSymbol` you have this symbol:

```
$\upVdash$
```

**Edit**

This MWE contains a solution to create your own symbol from `\bot`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1ex\parindent 0in
\begin{document}
%Arguments to inset commands{overlay image}{base image}{V-offset}{H-offset}
\topinset{$\bot$}{$\bot$}{-1pt}{}%
\end{document}
```

I used the solution provided here [Overlay symbol with another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another) to create it.

Comment: However that package will change all the other symbols unsed in the doc

Comment: This symbol is also in package `fdsymbol`; does it change something for your document? Does it significantly change your symbols?

Comment: Thanks! I do get some errors by adding the fdsymbol or mnsymbol packages ("too many math alphabets used"). But \upVdash is not quite what I'm looking for. The spacing between the horizontal lines seems too big and makes it hard to discern from equal signs in equations. What I forgot to mention is that I'd like to use it in conjunction with \Bot (cmll package), but \Bot and \upVdash have different base lines and different widths.

Comment: @Lopezo from looking at the code, yes

Answer (score 1):

Like Lopezeo who answered before me, this uses the `stackengine` approach.  But it is also made to work with different math styles, and like egreg's answer, conforms to the size of `\bot`.  It is also set `\mathord`, so that it is ready to use in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1ex\parindent 0in
\newcommand\Bot{\mathord{\stretchrel*{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{1.5\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\bot$}{$\SavedStyle\bot$}}}{\bot}}}
\begin{document}
$ A \bot B \Bot C $

$\scriptstyle A \bot B \Bot C$

$\scriptscriptstyle A \bot B \Bot C$
\end{document}
```

[image]