# Stylized epsilon ampersand

Tags: symbols, ampersand

I know in the written form, ampersands have a fair amount of variation beyond the standard *&*.

One I have seen and used frequently is what we will call the *epsilon ampersand*.

I was curious if there were any means of implementing this within LaTeX.

I have included a picture liberated from the ampersand Wikipedia entry.

[image]

Comment: I guess you may need to find a font for that symbol.

Comment: If you know how to do it, you also may combine Unicode chars U+0301, U+0317 and U+03B5 of some font that has them, for example DejaVu Sans.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I did not realize you could overlay multiple characters on top of each other.  I believe that is the path to achieving what I am looking to do.  Thanks.

Comment: If you manage to do it, you can answer your own question; it may be useful for other users, thank you!

Comment: You will find http://www.alain.les-hurtig.org/pdf/esperluettes-total.pdf amusing.

Comment: @ Thérèse That is pretty impressive, there were a few versions I haven't run into before.  It's impressive how far something can be reconfigured and still be recognizable as the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution inspired by Carla's suggestion to generate an epsilon ampersand for use in text mode. It should be compiled by XeLaTeX, using the Dejavu Sans font family.

### Generating from Unicode characters

I combined the Unicode characters [U+03B5](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b5/index.htm), [U+0375](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0375/index.htm) and [U+02B9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2B9/index.htm). Not exactly the ones that Carla suggested in the comments, but I find these to work just fine as well.

**Sample image:**

[image: unicode]

**Code**

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase]{LinLibertine} % Not necessary in main document

% ----------------------------------------------------------%
\newfontfamily\myfont{DejaVu Sans Condensed} 

\def\myamp{{\myfont%
    \raisebox{0.4\depth}{%
    {\scalebox{1}[0.81]{\char"03B5}}% epsilon
    {\scalebox{1}[0.6]{\raisebox{-0.18ex}{\kern-0.69ex\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\char"0375}}}}% bottom stroke
    {\scalebox{1}[0.6]{\raisebox{0.43ex}{\kern-0.31ex\char"02B9}}}% top stroke
}}}
% ----------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit. 
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit.
    Some birds \myamp{} some cats are hanging out in the garden.
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit. 
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit.
    
    This \myamp{} that. Cats \myamp{} dogs. Apples \myamp{} oranges. Dollars \myamp{} Euros. Epsilon \myamp{} strokes.
    
    In math mode: $1 \myamp{} 1 = 2$.
    
    \bigskip
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.1pt}%
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}%
    {\tiny tiny: \myamp{}, \fbox{\myamp{}}\par}
    {\footnotesize footnotesize: \myamp{}, \fbox{\myamp{}}\par}
    {\normalsize normal: \myamp{}, \fbox{\myamp{}}\par}
    {\large large: \myamp{}, \fbox{\myamp{}}\par}
    {\LARGE LARGE: \myamp{}, \fbox{\myamp{}}\par}
    {\Huge Huge: \myamp{}, \fbox{\myamp{}}\par}

\end{document}
```

**Comments:**

- It was definitely a lot of trial and error, this one. It's also probably not the most efficient way to do this, as I'm not very familiar with the commands used to resize/rescale boxes. I'm welcome to suggestions.
- Note the use of the braces in `\myamp{}`, which is necessary for proper spacing without resorting to using `xparse` package (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290504/117534)) or hardcoding it into the macro definition. You could, if you want, if you're only ever going to use it as a standalone character.
- I set the main font in my example as Libertine. Note that you don't have to in your main document -- I just found that the ampersand looks nicer when the rest of the text body is in Libertine font.
- The units used to scale the boxes are in `ex`'s (1ex is the height of the letter x in the current font), which allows the symbol to scale according to the font size of the surrounding text.

---

### Generating in pdfLaTeX with \includegraphics

Another approach is by inserting a vector graphic, instead of generating it by yourself from unicode characters (saves all the work to optimize the heights/widths of the boxes etc.). I took the liberty to convert the `.png` file from [Wikipedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Epsilon_Ampersand.png) to an `.svg` file using Inkscape.

I then exported the `.svg` file into a `.pdf` file to include directly in a macro I call `\pdfamp`. You can find the `.pdf` file which I created from `.svg` [here](http://ge.tt/5GNkTrj2). The scaling of the graphic is done with the wonderful [`scalerel`](http://mirror.pregi.net/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/scalerel/scalerel.pdf) package, scaled to the size of an actual ampersand sign. *This could probably use with some more tweaking*, but this is the result:

**Sample image**

[image: pdf]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % Once again, not necessary in the main document
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}

\def\pdfamp{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{myamp}}{\&}}

\begin{document}
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit. 
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit.
    Some birds \pdfamp{} some cats are hanging out in the garden.
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit. 
    This is a test of some very long message that has no meaning. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetuer adipiscing elit.
    
    This \pdfamp{} that. Cats \pdfamp{} dogs. Apples \pdfamp{} oranges. Dollars \pdfamp{} Euros. Epsilon \pdfamp{} strokes.
    
    \bigskip
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.1pt}%
    \setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}%
    {\tiny tiny: \pdfamp{}, \fbox{\pdfamp{}}\par}
    {\footnotesize footnotesize: \pdfamp{}, \fbox{\pdfamp{}}\par}
    {\normalsize normal: \pdfamp{}, \fbox{\pdfamp{}}\par}
    {\large large: \pdfamp{}, \fbox{\pdfamp{}}\par}
    {\LARGE LARGE: \pdfamp{}, \fbox{\pdfamp{}}\par}
    {\Huge Huge: \pdfamp{}, \fbox{\pdfamp{}}\par}
\end{document}
```

**Comments:**

- The Libertine font loaded here is once again, not required in the main font. But I tried this with Computer Modern, and it looks horrendous. But use it however you wish.
- The `.pdf` file of the epsilon ampersand converted from `.svg` can be found [here](http://ge.tt/5GNkTrj2). If this ever gets taken down, you can attempt to convert the `.png` from Wikipedia Commons to `.svg`/`.pdf` yourself using Inkscape -- it's fairly simple.
- Note the use of braces in `\pdfamp{}`, for proper spacing in text mode.

Comment: That is far more expansive than my quick fix solution.  The SVG solution I didn't even think about, I'll keep that in the back of my head for the next time some odd symbol comes up that I can't track down.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question cropped up using different symbols, desired end result is the same. [Overlay symbol with another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another)  However, I feel like it could still use some work, as the epsilon should probably be centered vertically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\Eamp{\mathrel{%
        \mathchoice{\eamp}{\eamp}{\scriptsize\eamp}{\tiny\eamp}%
}}
\def\eamp{{%
        \setbox0\hbox{/}%
        \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss$\varepsilon$\hss}}\box0
}}

\textwidth=2cm
\begin{document}

    $ A \Eamp B $

\end{document}
```

[image: Epsilon Ampersand attempt]

Comment: Your symbol is not exactly like the OP desire. The line doesn't cross the epsilon in the OP's image.

Comment: Moreover, this symbol is in math mode, whereas I think the OP wants it in text mode.