# Make TikZ symbol behave like constant

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

Answering this question: [Overlay a 0 with a |](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615331/8650)
I made this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\zerobar}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, overlay]
\node[anchor=base] {$0$};
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1.5ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
Test in text \zerobar{} test $0$ test\\
Test in math $\zerobar{}+2=0+2$
\end{document}
```

[image: Text]

How do I make `\zerobar` behave like `0` with the correct spacing in math?

I was thinking `\DeclareMathSymbol`, but I am not even sure that it is used for this or that it can be used here. I do not fully understand the examples given here:

https://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node18.html

or here:

https://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/amsfonts.pdf

Comment: you have a space before and after the tikzpicture in your definition, you are misisng `%` from ends of lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes - stupid :o) Removing spaces and `overlay` helps, but still not correct.

Comment: you don't  need any math declaration (unless you want to support \scriptsize)  just ensure that the tikz picture has the same dimensions as the 0

Comment: don't put the answer in the question:-) decalremathsymbol is for declaring which glyph to use from a font, not useful here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help from @DavidCarlisle, I got the correct spacing with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\zerobar}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[anchor=base, inner sep=0] {$0$};
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1.5ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
Test in text \zerobar{} test $0$ test\\
Test in math $\zerobar{}+2=0+2$
\end{document}
```

[image: Test text with correct spacing]

I am still not sure, if the TikZ picture behaves in the same way as `0` in all situations regards to spacing.

Comment: For your final sentence: 0 has no spacing rules, it's a mathord so has teh smae spacing as the tikz box but you this will be like `\mbox{$0$}` which is your basic node, so it won't get smaller in subscripts, you could modify it to use `\mathpallette` as in the other aanswers in that question.