# Is there a built-in symbol for a strictly one-sided material conditional?

Tags: symbols, logic

Is there a built-in symbol like

[image]

If it does not exist, what method do you recommend to make such a symbol?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara?

Comment: You could try to make yourself, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615382/make-tikz-symbol-behave-like-constant for an example.

Comment: @CampanIgnis That's a nice app but I couldn't find the symbol...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\harpoonswidth}
\settowidth{\harpoonswidth}{$\rightleftharpoons$}
\newcommand*{\circnotharpoons}{%
    \mathrel{\ooalign{%
        $\rightleftharpoons$\cr%
        \makebox[\harpoonswidth]{%
            \begin{picture}(10,10)(-5,0)
                \put(0,3.5){\circle{2}}
            \end{picture}%
        }\cr%
        \makebox[\harpoonswidth]{%
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{%
                \rule[.3pt]{.4pt}{2.5pt}%
            }%
        }%
    }}%
}
\begin{document}
\(A \circnotharpoons B\)

\(A \rightleftharpoons B\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want! Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a version that also changes size in subscripts and superscripts, maintaining the correct line width for the circle and the slash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
% line thickness
\newcommand{\hermis@thickness}[1]{%
  \fontdimen8
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
}
% width for the decoration
\newcommand{\hermis@width}[1]{%
  0.2\fontdimen6
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 2
}
% distance
\newcommand{\hermis@distance}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 0.12\fontdimen6\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle 0.12\fontdimen6\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 0.075\fontdimen6\scriptfont\else
  0.0385\fontdimen6\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 2
}
% circle
\newcommand{\hermis@circle}[1]{%
  $#1\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{picture}(1,1)
  \put(0.5,0.5){\arc{0.5}}
  \end{picture}}}$%
}
% slash
\newcommand{\hermis@slash}[1]{%
  $#1\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{picture}(1,1)
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
  \end{picture}}}$%
}
% the main command
\newcommand{\sosmc}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\hermis@sosmc\relax}}
\newcommand{\hermis@sosmc}[2]{%
  \begingroup\m@th
  \vcenter{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\hermis@width{#1}}%
    \linethickness{\hermis@thickness{#1}}%
    \hbox{\ooalign{%
      $#1\rightharpoonup$\cr
      \hidewidth\hermis@circle{#1}\hidewidth\cr
    }}%
    \nointerlineskip\vskip-\hermis@distance{#1}%
    \hbox{\ooalign{%
      $#1\leftharpoondown$\cr
      \hidewidth\hermis@slash{#1}\hidewidth\cr
    }}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\sosmc B$

$\scriptstyle A\sosmc B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A\sosmc B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Not too sure what exactly you want, but I propose this code, based on the `\stackinset` command which hopefully is not too far from what you'd like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine} 

\newcommand{\Orightharpoonup}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c} {0pt}{c}{0.5pt}{\circ}{\relbar\mkern-3.2mu\rightharpoonup}}}%
\newcommand{\nleftharpoondown}{\mathrel{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-4pt}{c}{0.5pt}{\not}{\leftharpoondown\mkern-3.2mu\relbar}}}%

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{matrix}
A \Orightharpoonup B \\
D \nleftharpoondown C
 \end{matrix}\]%


\[A \mathrel{\begin{matrix}
 \Orightharpoonup \\[-1.5ex]
 \nleftharpoondown
 \end{matrix}} B \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, it looks great! But I have to admit my request was not that clear. I want to make it a single symbol as shown in the figure I've just updated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: And the boundary line is not an intended one :)

Comment: @Hermis14: I've modified the second code. Please see if it befits you.

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you. I wish I could select both answers.

Comment: It's not that important…

Comment: @Bernard my aplogies, Fat finger on the downvote I can't make it up :/